# django query: get objects where only 'time' is greater than HH:mm no matter what the date is?

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset, django-orm

I have a model called, `MinutePrice`, which has a `DateTimeField` as one of fields.

What I want to do is making query of objects whose time is greater than 15:30, no matter what the date is.

What I've tried:

`MinuetePrice.objects.filter(Q(date_time__lte="15:30"))`

Errors occured:

`ValidationError: ["'15:30' value has an invalid format. It must be in YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM[:ss[.uuuuuu]][TZ] format."]`

Any ideas to solve this?

Answer (score 2):

The [__time](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#time) filter can be used for this

```
MinuetePrice.objects.filter(date_time__time__gt=datetime.time(15, 30))
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a datetime object to compare, you cannot compare it to a string directly.

```
datetime.time(15,30)
```

It should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you want get all record have time greater than 15:30, you can try Django query like this:

`MinuetePrice.objects.filter(Q(timestamp__hour__gte=16) | Q(timestamp__hour__gte=15, timestamp__minute__gte=30))`

Document in this [queryset time](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#time)